# How to create a multiSelectable List or a checkBoxGroup in LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am working on LWUIT 1.4 and in my current application I want to display a list to the user and user can select choices as many as possible.. For other simple cases (where only single selection is allowed)  I have used ComboBox but for the multiple selection I really need a better solution.

Any code snippet of lwuit List or ChoiceGroup with checkboxes will be of a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article, [LWUIT List Checkbox.](http://lumbungilmu.com/?p=271)  It will helps you and also see this [discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810630/list-with-checkbox-using-lwuit-in-j2me)