# TextField not updating dynamically

Tags: java, swing, java-me, lwuit

this is a really simple code in which text on a button is copied to a TextField.
The code works fine but the TextField is not updating instantly on clicking the button.
It updates only after i click on the TextField or when i drag the form not on pressing the button instantly.
why is this happening,this behavior is unexpected.
i am testing this code on a nokia 501 emulator which supports LWUIT.

```
           a = new Form("CALCULATOR")
                   final TextArea data = new TextArea();
           final Button ab = new Button("Some Value");
           ab.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                data.setText(ab.getText());

            }

           });
           a.addComponent(ab);
           a.addComponent(data);
           a.show();
                   }
```

Comment: hmm ... now which framework is it? Looks at least unrelated to Swing (Button is a AWT component in desktop context)

Comment: its LWUIT 
it's quite similar to swing , that's why i added the swing tag

Answer (score 5):

After setting the text in the textfield repaint it. This may work

```
  data.setText(ab.getText());
  data.validate(); or data.repaint();
```

Comment: FYI you need only the validate. Its not a painting issue its a layout issue, the text field needs to grow. You should also accept pundit's answer and ideally vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

That happen because your Code.
I explain:

you call to function actionPerformed: this is lisitner that call when user make action like "after i click on the TextField..".

what you need to do is simple:

```
  a = new Form("CALCULATOR")
               final TextArea data = new TextArea();
       final Button ab = new Button("Some Value");
       ab.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       data.setText(ab.getText());
       a.addComponent(ab);
       a.addComponent(data);
       a.show();
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          a = new Form("CALCULATOR")
                   final TextArea data = new TextArea();
           final Button ab = new Button("Some Value");
           ab.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              //  data.setText(ab.getText()); // You should not use this

                // Use this instead
                  data.setText(ab.getActionCommand());

            }

           });
           a.addComponent(ab);
           a.addComponent(data);
           a.show();
                   }
```