# Add textfields dynamically in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

So I have this code here, and it is supposed to dynamically add textfields and buttons depending on how many times the user presses `New Column` however it is not adding anything.

```
newColumn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                String column = columns.getText();
                columns.clear();
                final HBox hbox1 = new HBox();
                final TextField textField = new TextField();
                textField.setText(column);
                Button delete = new Button("X");
                vbox.getChildren().add(hbox1);

                delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                        vbox.getChildren().remove(hbox1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the part of the code that is supposed to add the new buttons. Here's the rest of the code, that displays the window and everythig else:

```
package GUI;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Parameters");
    primaryStage.setWidth(500);
    primaryStage.setHeight(800);

    showWindow(scene);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void showWindow(Scene scene){
    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    final HBox hbox = new HBox();
    final TextField columns = new TextField();
    Button newColumn = new Button("New Column");
    Button done = new Button("Done");

    hbox.setSpacing(5);
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(columns, newColumn);
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 20));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox);

    newColumn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                String column = columns.getText();
                columns.clear();
                final HBox hbox1 = new HBox();
                final TextField textField = new TextField();
                textField.setText(column);
                Button delete = new Button("X");
                vbox.getChildren().add(hbox1);

                delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                        vbox.getChildren().remove(hbox1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(done);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

}
```

}

I'm also using JavaFX, if that helps.

Comment: Are you [repainting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305584/textfield-not-updating-dynamically?rq=1) the textfield?

Comment: No, I'm trying to add textfields each time a person press the button "New Column", or more specifically, I'm trying to add hboxes each time a person presses that button. However it isn't adding those boxes to my vbox or it isn't displaying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be dynamic in adding and removing `JComponents` , consider storing them in an `ArrayList` or `Vector`. In the start, there will be a default `JTextField` and then then user will add one after another.

In the `actionPerformed()` of the `JButton`, create a new `JTextField` of whatever size you want. Call `invalidate()` on the content pane of your `JFrame` and then just add whatever component you need.

Good to go !

**SSCCE**

```
package stack;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DynamicButtons extends JFrame{

    JButton addMore = new JButton("AddMore");
    Container contentPane = null;

    public DynamicButtons(){

        contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        addMore.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton newButton = new JButton("ABCD");
                contentPane.invalidate();
                contentPane.add(newButton);
                pack();

            }
        });

        contentPane.add(addMore);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new DynamicButtons();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**The OP needs JavaFX**
1. Get your whatever `Pane` you are using.
2. Call the `yourPane.getChildren()`
3. In the listener of the button, just add the child to the list you obtained above

Comment: I can do that, or the equivalent in JavaFX, however I'd need to add this arraylist every time a new column is entered. I don't suppose that will be a problem?

Comment: @Argus You should have tagged it as `JavaFX` -_-"

Comment: I forgot about that, in any case, this is still useful.

Comment: @Argus I am in a rush so I posted steps instead for JavaFX. Have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I was actually implementing it.

Comment: and +1 it if you are extra generous.. :D

Comment: Yeah, its doing exactly what I need it do. Thanks.